# What's wrong with this MYSQL query?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
delimiter |

CREATE FUNCTION BASE64_DECODE (input BLOB)
        RETURNS BLOB
        CONTAINS SQL
        DETERMINISTIC
        SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
        DECLARE ret BLOB DEFAULT '';
        DECLARE done TINYINT DEFAULT 0;

        IF input IS NULL THEN
                RETURN NULL;
        END IF;

each_block:
        WHILE NOT done DO BEGIN
                DECLARE accum_value BIGINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
                DECLARE in_count TINYINT DEFAULT 0;
                DECLARE out_count TINYINT DEFAULT 3;

each_input_char:
                WHILE in_count < 4 DO BEGIN
                        DECLARE first_char CHAR(1);

                        IF LENGTH(input) = 0 THEN
                                RETURN ret;
                        END IF;

                        SET first_char = SUBSTRING(input,1,1);
                        SET input = SUBSTRING(input,2);

                        BEGIN
                                DECLARE tempval TINYINT UNSIGNED;
                                DECLARE error TINYINT DEFAULT 0;
                                DECLARE base64_getval CURSOR FOR SELECT val FROM base64_data WHERE c = first_char;
                                DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET error = 1;

                                OPEN base64_getval;
                                FETCH base64_getval INTO tempval;
                                CLOSE base64_getval;

                                IF error THEN
                                        ITERATE each_input_char;
                                END IF;

                                SET accum_value = (accum_value << 6) + tempval;
                        END;

                        SET in_count = in_count + 1;

                        IF first_char = '=' THEN
                                SET done = 1;
                                SET out_count = out_count – 1;
                        END IF;
                END; END WHILE;

                WHILE out_count > 0 DO BEGIN
                        SET ret = CONCAT(ret,CHAR((accum_value & 0xff0000) >> 16));
                        SET out_count = out_count – 1;
                        SET accum_value = (accum_value << 8) & 0xffffff;
                END; END WHILE;

        END; END WHILE;

        RETURN ret;
END |
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '– 1;
                        END IF;
                END; END WHILE;
         ' at line 52
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, silly as it was, was the use of non-standard symbols throughout. -s and 's were wrong format. Due to the encoding of the IDE I am using or something just as silly.

facepalm

Answer (score 3):

`WHILE` loops in MySQL are simply terminated with `END WHILE;`. You've got `END; END WHILE;` which is incorrect.

Comment: "END;" ends the "BEGIN", inside the while loop.  I would try without the "BEGIN ... END;" as Marc suggests.

Comment: hmm, I've removed `END;` in `END; END WHILE;` and I'm getting a similar error with the new code...

Comment: WHILE loops also don't need a `BEGIN`.  `WHILE ... DO .... END;` is the proper syntax.

Comment: This, unfortunately, wasn't the problem. As neil points out, the `END;` ends the `BEGIN` further up. No problem there. Tried with/without and no difference.

Answer (score 0):

That `END` before `END WHILE;` is causing the problem. You already have an END on line 46, so this one is trying to end the function. I'll bet you can just remove it.